# xbindkey: press key two times in a row for a different output

Tags: shortcut-keys, xdotool, xbindkeys

I recently discovered xbindkeys and xdotool. I was wondering if there is way to remap a key to a different one if pressed two times in a row?

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: I want to start "Guake Terminal" if I press CTRL two times in a row (fast).